# Open files with variable filenames

Tags: r, file, arguments

I read a matlab file with the R.matlab package and get a number from it as a list. I turn it into a numeric:

```
library(R.matlab)

# simple case: static filename

setwd("C:/Files/Fold")
nc <- readMat('passvar1.mat')

nC <- as.numeric(nc)
nC
## 10
```

More complex cast: I need to open file in folder in R with `nC` in name: `C:/Files/Coordinates/CoordsRS%nC%.md.txt`

All files have same name apart from number, for example:

```
 C:/Files/Coordinates/CoordsR4.md.txt
 C:/Files/Coordinates/CoordsR10.md.txt
```

and, I need to apply operation to this file contents (i.e. pass in a parameter to `readMat` so it can read them dynamically)

Comment: @hrbrmstr. I don't think it's duplicate as I tried that. it doesn't work. newC <- lapply("C:/Folder/corrd/*nC.md.txt", read.table)
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'C:/.../*nC.md.txt': Invalid argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be easiest to build the file names either with a `paste0` or `sprintf` call. For example

```
nC <- 10
paste0("C:/Files/Coordinates/CoordsR", nC, ".md.txt")
# [1] "C:/Files/Coordinates/CoordsR10.md.txt"
sprintf("C:/Files/Coordinates/CoordsR%d.md.txt",nC)
# [1] "C:/Files/Coordinates/CoordsR10.md.txt"
```

`sprintf()` has many more options when it comes to padding with leading zeros or otherwise formatting the number before inserting into the string. You can then pass these filenames to `readMat()`

Comment: Thank you. I didn't post that I have tried sprintf too and I get what I need but its class is character.> xx <- sprintf("C:/Folder/Coordinates/%s",nC). How to use this char to open this filename in folder? I don't pass filenames to readMat(). i need to read nC from readMat() and use this nC open file in the folder in R.

Comment: Just use `readMat(xx)` or `read.table(xx)` or however you want to open the file. Why does that not work? What do you want to do with this path?

Comment: Thank you. read.table(xx) did the job. readMat(xx) returns and error:rror in mat5ReadTag(this) : 
  Unknown data type. Not in range [1,19]: 11829
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In readMat5Header(this, firstFourBytes = firstFourBytes) :
  Unknown endian: -6. Will assume Bigendian.
2: In readMat5Header(this, firstFourBytes = firstFourBytes) :
  Unknown MAT version tag: 2336. Will assume version 5.